# How to use single sign on for dropbox?

Tags: javascript, oauth, single-sign-on, dropbox

I am connecting my JavaScript app to my [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) to upload / download files. As part of oauth process, I have to redirect the user to dropbox API page that presents a permission Allow / Deny dialog. Is there any way to get this dialog skipped?

I believe this could be possible via SSO but don't know how I can achieve it for dropbox. Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: +1 looking forward this question. Its something which i would also like to know.

Comment: some confusion here, maybe, as sso is what you want to obtain, not the way you're gonna get it.

Comment: So you want Dropbox to allow any application access to your files without getting your permission?

Comment: ZJR, what if I want to integrate it with my Gmail account where I am already logged in?

Comment: Quetin, yes, but not without being logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dropbox API's [oauth/authorize](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#authorize) method does not provide a way for users to skip the allow/deny with previously authorized applications.

Comment: Thanks Abraham, but how about accessing the dropbox via some desktop application? Does it also require the same Allow / Deny dialog?

Comment: Yes. Dropbox is not going to allow you to access anyones data without them explicitly allowing it.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to use the same dropbox account regarless of user just store the access_token generated after first acceptance and re-use it. The access_token can be seen in session variable. Just set it manually and you won't be redirected to dropbox authorization page.

Comment: Yes I did the same thing and stored it separately for different users.